# Mass Edit/Update List View Field?

Tags: fields, list-view

I have to add "Domestic Support" field to 460 Case List Views...

Is there a way to do this in bulk or do I have to do these one by one?

[image]

Comment: You cannot from the UI as far as I know but you can utilize [`ListView` metadata](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_listview.htm) to do so and utilize the `columns` attribute.

Comment: There's several ways you can do this. If they all share the same record type you can do inline editing within the view. You have to specify the record type as a condition. You can also use the data loader to export the records (using the same filters as the list view), make your adjustments, then re-import using the data loader.